# Cannot customize the classpath of Eclipse JUnit Debug Configuration

Tags: eclipse, maven, testing, junit, classpath

In VS Code, I managed to configure the classpath for running the tests using `settings.json` section `"java.test.config" / "classPaths"`. I set the `"testKind""` to `"junit"` and added the list of jar files in the array `"classPaths"`. I was so happy that it worked.

I tried to do the same from Eclipse, and I thought the way to do that is using Debug Configuration. I did my best to add the needed jars the  `Dependencies` tab, and it is not working at all. When I click "Show Command", I see a huge list of classpath entries which are coming from Maven Dependencies. No matter what I do, when I debug, I see that the execution is going to a wrong jar under Maven.

The question is how I can ensure that the unwanted jars are removed from the classpath when running the test?

I tried to add the snapshot to clarify and the link to the image appears to be broken. I will try to fix it later.

[image: Eclipse Debug Configuration]

Comment: If you have used Maven you have defined everything in Maven (pom.xml) and NOT in Eclipse anymore... the base is your pom file. (the single truth)... Does you build work on plain command line (not from within your IDE etc.) ...?

Comment: @khmarbaise that makes sense. Yes, the build, and unit testing with debugging works correctly in all cases. It is just this case where I want to override two JARs with others. They are needed for Encryption/Decryption to work properly during the test. By the way, do you see the snapshot I added?

Comment: How do you do this override outside of Eclipse? Outside of VSCode?

Comment: @nitind I suppose you do that using some exclude instructions in pom.xml. I can look this up but haven't done that before. In the meantime, if you can help, please let me know, whether to change it in Eclipse or pom.xml.

Comment: In the launch configuration you can remove the _Maven Dependencies_ node and add JARs manually. If you specify the dependency in a different project, you can also add this project, but you have to export the dependencies in that project first: _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Order and Export_. But better find a Maven way to do it, so everyone can run those tests everywhere.

Comment: @howlger I used the Run/Debug Config dialog box, in the tab `(x) = Arguments`. I added `-classpath` to the `VM Arguments` box. I removed the Maven node from the `Dependencies` tab. When I clicked `Show Command` I now see the `-classpath` argument twice and Maven Dependencies are not removed. All I want is to remove or override the unwanted jars that are generated by Eclipse. Why it was so easy to do in VS Code?

Comment: If you don't want to simply use the UI (just hit the _Add JARs_ button), you can also save the launch configuration somewhere in your workspace (in the _Common_ tab choose _Shared file_) and edit the the XML. If you do not want to be bound to the settings of a specific project, you must not choose that specific project in the _Main_ tab. But as already said, better use Maven, so everyone can run those tests everywhere (e.g. via properties or profiles).

Comment: I found the solution. See the added answer for details. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by customizing the classpath for the referenced projects. The main project A was referencing project B. I had to remove unwanted dependencies from pom.xml in A and B and added a `userlib` (folder) with the needed jar files to project B since the failing classes were in project B. From Java Build Path/Libraries/Add Library/User Library. Configure the userlib to point to a userlib folder under the main project folder with the needed jars.

After that, the classpath was updated successfully in the `.classpath` file as follows:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/userlib"/>
```

Then, it worked like a charm. There was no need to update any classpath in the Debug Configuration box. Now, I am able to run the test from Project A that will call the classes/method in Project B and it passed successfully.

I faced this problem because the needed jar files which are installed in the local Maven repositories are not the correct ones, so I had to pick the correct ones from a proper working instance in the local environment.